# How to select columns where value is not zero

Tags: c#, mysql

How do you select columns where the value is not zero?

If I have 3 columns

```
column1|column2|column3
-------+-------+-------
   0   |   50  |   99
```

I want the query to show only columns that have values > 0

so that the result will be

```
column2|column3
-------+-------
   50  |   99
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `column1` != '0'
```

Comment: Column list in SQL cannot be dynamic(at least not without prepared statements)

Comment: This is not how SQL works. A where clause will only filter the rows returned. The columns must be specified. What you can do is retrieve all the values and process them in your code.

Comment: You're only showing one row of data. What would be the expected output if the next row had a value set in `column1`?

Comment: I guess you're already aware, but this kind of problem is highly symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: @Strawberry - very true. But thats a common position for devs to end up in and have no option to alter a legacy database. Creative answers to weird questions are a big part of what makes SO such a valuable resource IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Would a json string containing the columns work for your purposes?

```
SELECT CONCAT(COALESCE(CASE WHEN column1 > 0 THEN JSON_OBJECT('column1', column1) END, ''), 
              COALESCE(CASE WHEN column2 > 0 THEN JSON_OBJECT('column2', column2) END, ''), 
              COALESCE(CASE WHEN column3 > 0 THEN JSON_OBJECT('column3', column3) END, '')
             )
FROM table1;
```

This will return a json string only containing the columns that are > 0. So using your example this would return `{"column2": 50}{"column3": 99}`

Answer (score 1):

SQL returns tables of data.  Tables have the same columns on every row.  You cannot have a query where a column is missing in a row.

So if this `select` statement:

```
select column1, column2, column3 from table1
```

returns

```
column1 | column2 | column3
    1   |    20   |   50
    0   |    12   |    2
    3   |    15   |    0
   10   |     0   |   11
```

what do you expect would be in the first column of the second row if we omit columns with zeros?

The best you can do is replace zeros with NULL.

```
select CASE WHEN column1 > 0 THEN column1 ELSE NULL END,
       CASE WHEN column2 > 0 THEN column2 ELSE NULL END,
       CASE WHEN column3 > 0 THEN column3 ELSE NULL END
from table1
```

Which would give us this:

```
column1 | column2 | column3
    1   |    20   |   50
  NULL  |    12   |    2
    3   |    15   |  NULL
   10   |   NULL  |   11
```